# jquery plugin for numbered navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know where i could find a jquery plugin (or any other solution) that will help me to make a 'youtube like' comment navigation. See the link.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pu9rv6hbbocqcyi/IEi8f6gn85#f:youtube_nav.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : jQuery Pagination

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

You just have to customize the css of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clean and elegant solution to your requirement

[jQuery Paginate](http://web.enavu.com/js/jquery/jpaginate-jquery-pagination-system-plugin/)